# GDB - Identify where the Segmentation Fault occurs

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, segmentation-fault

I get a Segmentation Fault in my program and I used GDB to debug it. The following is my backtrace in GDB:

```
#0  __memcpy_ssse3_back () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-back.S:199
#1  0x00007f054885b6ef in ViSpectrumAnalyzer::run (this=0x991e98) at vispectrumanalyzer.cpp:66
#2  0x00007f05488573e8 in ViProcessorList::manipulateInput (this=0x991b00, data=0xdf2c30) at viprocessorlist.cpp:64
#3  0x00007f0548852a3b in ViMultiExecutor::runNotify (this=0x991ab0) at vimultiexecutor.cpp:34
#4  0x00007f0548855f9d in ViExecutor::connect (this=0xc104ca031a0, processor=0x1059f0) at viexecutor.cpp:227
#5  0x00007f054c416cd8 in QThreadPrivate::start(void*) () from libQtCore.so.5
#6  0x00007f054a35ae9a in start_thread (arg=0x7f0530e4a700) at pthread_create.c:308
#7  0x00007f054bbb34bd in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:112
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

If I test my program, the backtrace #1 is always in the run function of ViSpectrumAnalyzer. However it is always at a different place (+- 5 lines). My question now: does the above backtrace actually indicate that the SegFault happens in ViSpectrumAnalyzer::run().backtrace #0 mentiones memcpy, which I use a couple of lines later (but not on line 66). With the example above, line 66 is a statement:

```
int size = windowSize - bufferSize;
```

with windowSize and bufferSize both integers. So I don’t think the SegFault can actually happen there. I have to add that I’m pretty sure some of my classes can cause problems since they are not thread-safe (eg: no mutex).

Comment: First thing, make sure that the source code and the binary are in sync.

Comment: I've deleted evrything and built from scratch.

Comment: With optimization turned on, your compiler is free to shuffle fragments of code. If the segfault can be reproduced with -O0, the stack trace will be more accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. What exactly is -O0?

Comment: GCC offers different levels of ooptimization. Level 0 is none at all. Read full details at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: or "-Og" as it is said here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html . "It is a better choice than -O0 for producing debuggable code because some compiler passes that collect debug information are disabled at -O0."